# Can't change label size in html/css

Tags: html, css, label

Tried different ways:

- inline
- class
- id

nothing works, I can't change the size of label blocks in html/css

Here is part of code

```css
.label {
  size: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Quadratic Equation Roots Calculator</h1>
<h3> This web page finds the roots of a polynomial equation of the following form:<br>
  <i>ax<sup>2</sup> + bx + c</i> = 0<br>
  <i>a, b,</i> and<i> c </i> must be integers between -99 and +99, and <i>a </i>must be non-zero.<br><br>


  <form class="label">
    <label for="a"> <b>a:</b></label>
    <input type="number" id="a" size="5" min="-99" max="+99" required="nonzero">
    <label for="b"><b>b:</b></label>
    <input type="number" name="b" size="5" min="-99" max="+99" required>
    <label for="c"> <b>c:</b>
        <input type="number" name="c" size="5" min="-99" max="+99" required> </label>
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Calculate Root" onclick="calculateRoots"> </form>
```

Comment: Do you mean `label {
      font-size: 5px;
    }`

Comment: Also you forgot to close the h3

Comment: try using `font-size:15px;` than `size`.

Comment: Why you have `max="+99"` in `<input>`? I think you want to make sure that you can only raise to 99. Then you must remove + before 99 --> `max="99"`.

Comment: thank you,just studying,a lot of mistakes

Comment: Omg, just closed <h3>, and fixed +99 .and everything is ok ,(for now:)) ).Will continue in the evening with js ,so more question coming. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to target the attribute like so:

```
label[for="a"] {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

I hope that helps in some way.

Answer (score -2):

If you mean label width you can use this code:

```css
label {
 display: block; width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Quadratic Equation Roots Calculator</h1>
<h3> This web page finds the roots of a polynomial equation of the following form:<br>
  <i>ax<sup>2</sup> + bx + c</i> = 0<br>
  <i>a, b,</i> and<i> c </i> must be integers between -99 and +99, and <i>a </i>must be non-zero.</h3><br><br>


  <form class="label">
    <label for="a"> <b>a:</b></label>
    <input type="number" id="a" size="5" min="-99" max="+99" required="nonzero">
    <label for="b"><b>b:</b></label>
    <input type="number" name="b" size="5" min="-99" max="+99" required>
    <label for="c"> <b>c:</b>
      <input type="number" name="c" size="5" min="-99" max="+99" required> </label>
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Calculate Root" onclick="calculateRoots">
  </form>
```

If you mean `font-size` add it to css: `font-size:100px;`

Comment: Thank you, fixed, I needed 5px number container for all labels